# Semantics: alternative word for long-ranged interaction?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, interactions

I am working on wording for a report. I need to a word to describe long ranged interaction that is constant in strength. But I am aware that people sometimes use 'long-ranged' to mean decaying strength with $1/r$. I want to describe a constant interaction strength. Any suggestions for intuitive wording?

Comment: Such semantic soft-questions are better asked in e.g. the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Question was closed as I was finishing this answer...Let's coin a new word for a this concept:

Anatelic: from ana- (without), and tele (distance).

You define it once, and then use it. It doesn't exist (yet) and if your idea takes off, it will be known forever as "your" word.

Answer (score 1):

suggestions....

Distance-independant interaction

interaction that does not depend on $r$

interaction that is independent of distance

$r^0$ interaction

... of these the top one would be my favourite - sounds like a pretty unusual interaction that does not depend on $r$. If I was writing I would use the top term and explain it carefully the first time as it sounds so unusual to me. - and maybe occasionally use one of the other expressions below - I agree that 'long-range' does not really fit the bill here.